# How to disable the lockscreen in Windows 10 insider build 14367

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-insider

I tried doing this using the Group Policy Editor by navigating to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Personalization` and setting `Do not display the lock screen` to enabled. This worked before I had thid build in Windows 8 and the first release builds in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the registry as shown in [this post](http://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-disable-the-lock-screen-in-windows-10)

The steps are as followed

> 1. Press Windows Key + R and put regedit in Run dialog box to open Registry Editor then Click OK.
> 2. In the left pane of Registry Editor, navigate to following registry key:
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
> 3. Now highlight Windows key and right click, select New > Key. Name the newly created sub-key as Personalization. Highlight Personalization and come to its right pane. In the blank space, right click and select New > DWORD Value. Name the registry DWORD (REG_DWORD) so created as NoLockScreen. Double click on this DWORD to modify:
> 4. Finally, set the Value data to 1 in Edit DWORD Value box shown above. Click OK. You can now restart your machine to make this setting effective. After reboot, you’ll see the lock screen is no longer displayed.

Hope this helps you out!